# To show default image if screenshot of webpage captured using third party fails

Tags: php, screenshot

What i am trying to do is to capture screenshot of URL submitted by user and using http://open.thumbshots.org/image.aspx?url=http://google.com . The problem is, if for any reason screenshot don't get captured(as user can enter invalid url), what i get is default image of open.thumbshots.org saying "thumbshots.com Image coming soon" . How can i show my default image instead of that image in case of failure?

```
$url = $_POST['user_url'];
```

and html

```
 <img src="http://open.thumbshots.org/image.aspx?url=<?php echo $url;?>" width = "180" height = "150" />
```

Here i need to decide before showing image, if returned image is default image of thumbshots, display my default image

Comment: some of your code here, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely familiar with this particular service, and you haven't given us any code you are using to go on, but *my guess* is you have a few options:

1. **check the "expires" and/or "cache-control" headers** it seems like the default image is set to expire after 60 seconds for the default image, and 604800 seconds (or some larger value) fo a valid image.
2. **keep a copy of the default image locally, and compare it to the received image** if the image you keep locally is is the same as the returned, you know you have the default image
3. **Do (1) and (2)**
4. **Use another service, or do it yourself.**  For example, [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) (see also [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/cutycapt.1.html))

Personally, I really like CutyCapt because I can guarantee it's performance on my own servers and it's pretty easy to use.  But I don't know what your setup is like or what you've tried already, so it may not be possible for you.

If you are set on using thumbshots.org, I would suggest checking the headers, as that seems pretty consistently correct (although I've admittedly spent very little time checking).

Comment: I'm glad.  If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer so other people who have this problem can know it worked for you